# Restart android service after reboot device or removed from the recent apps tray

Tags: android-service, titanium, appcelerator, localnotification

Please, I'm using Android services in my app to launch local notifications, exactly as described [here](https://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/guides2/Android+Notifications), on Appcelerator Wiki. The services run well as expected but if the application is removed from the recent apps tray or device was rebooted, services stop.

I would like to the service still running after the app is removed from the recent apps tray or restart service after reboot device. How can I do it using classic Titanium.

In iOS version of my app I'm using Ti.App.iOS.scheduleLocalNotification and run very well, even after switching the device off and on. I wish that on Android worked the same way.

Thank You for any help.

(sorry for my bad english)

Answer (score 0):

You can try [benCoding.Android.Tools](https://github.com/benbahrenburg/benCoding.Android.Tools) module. check the [BootReceiver](https://github.com/benbahrenburg/benCoding.Android.Tools/blob/master/documentation/bootreceiver.md)

you can find an example [here](https://github.com/benbahrenburg/benCoding.Android.Tools/tree/master/example/BootReceiver) if you are using a service for notification you need to install the module and add the receiver to your tiapp.xml as in the example

Comment: Could you give an example?

Comment: @Blacksilver you can find an example https://github.com/benbahrenburg/benCoding.Android.Tools/tree/master/example/BootReceiver
if you are using a service for notification you need to install the module and add the receiver to your tiapp.xml as in the example